# Making an xorg.conf file results in a login loop for non-Wayland logins

Tags: 18.04, xorg, login, synaptics, xorg.conf

Ubuntu 18.04. Unlike in 16.04, which I upgraded from earlier this week, in order to get my Synaptics touchpad to work as I want it to, I've needed to make an xorg.conf file. However, after rebooting, I've found myself with the touchpad working as I want it to, but a login loop whenever I try to use anything but Ubuntu on Wayland. Deleting xorg.conf has fixed the problem, but reverted my touchpad back to its old undesirable behaviour.

Is there a solution to this? Or even a compromise?

EDIT: Attempts to solve the problem by deleting the xorg.conf file and instead using [a fragment file](https://pastebin.com/DpfUYAkA) have done little more than put me back in to the loop.

Comment: Did you create a full xorg conf file, or a fragment in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` related to just the touchpad? What is in the Xorg log file (should be in `~/.local/share/xorg`)? Please modify your question to provide this information.

Comment: I made a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.  The /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d folder already existed and has files that are relevant to the touchpad. The Xorg.0.log file is far too big to post or even summarize, where should I be looking?

Comment: I would suggest removing the `xorg.conf` file, and instead put just the section relevant to your touchpad in a fragment file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. That way you don't touch the rest of the xorg configuration.

Comment: Good idea. Do you have a link to a guide on how to make such a fragment file?

Comment: `man xorg.conf.d`, and you can probably just cut the `InputDevice` section from your `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: @zwets No success. I've made the file '80-synap.conf' in the directory with the contents found in https://pastebin.com/DpfUYAkA, but that's just brought me back in to the loop.

Comment: Did you remove the `xorg.conf` file? Did you remove any other cruft from `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`? Is the configuration inside a `Section "InputClass"` (or `InputDevice`, not sure) ... `EndSection`? Please edit your question to reflect what you have done so far, and where the problem is now, rather than continuing in the comments.

Comment: @zwets I'll make the edit now, but so far I've barely done anything. The xorg.conf file was already deleted, but adding in the '80-synap.conf' results in the login loop regardless of if I include 'Section "InputClass"' and ...EndSection or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I've solved it. All that was required was to paste the relevant parts in to the already existing '70-synaptics.conf' file found in the  /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d folder. As for what I mean by "the relevant parts", it seems that I only had to delete the 'Parameter settings:' line [from this code](https://pastebin.com/DpfUYAkA) however in practice I only pasted:

```
Option "TapButton1" "1"
Option "TapButton2" "0"
Option "TapButton3" "0"
Option "ClickFinger1" "1"
Option "ClickFinger2" "0"
Option "ClickFinger3" "0"
```

So the relevant section of my '70-synaptics.conf' file now looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "0"
    Option "TapButton3" "0"
    Option "ClickFinger1" "1"
    Option "ClickFinger2" "0"
    Option "ClickFinger3" "0"
EndSection
```